# How to change a variable based on the server URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that gets the server url:

```
var server = parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
```

I want to be able to console log different things based on the server URL so created an if created an if condition:

```
if(server = "www.homemysiteserver.com"){
  console.log("home page");
} else if(server = "www.aboutmysiteserver.com"){
  console.log("about page");
} else if(server = "www.infomysiteserver.com"){
  console.log("about page");
}
```

However this doesn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: is that valid one `parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();` .Whats they are return ? .For condition use `===` instead of `=`

Comment: You might also need the protocol. Also I second the above, what's wrong with window.location.href

Comment: In javascript compaire two values
if (x === y)

Comment: @prasanth parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl(); is valid and produces the correct result.

Comment: `=` is for [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), `==` or `===` is the [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

You should use strict equal to ensure that the server string is equal to a given value and of the same type. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison).

So instead of doing

```
if(server = "www.homemysiteserver.com")
```

you should be doing this

```
if(server === "www.homemysiteserver.com")
```

Also in case you want to simply to obtain the host url you can use the following:

`window.location.hostname`
 and this will give you homemysiteserver.com or any other value according to the url.

The same applies to all the other validations you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

As both Hugo Barona and Liam have pointed out, the original issue was that you were trying to compare the server names using the assignment operator `=`, instead of the comparison operators `==` or `===`. The difference between these is very well explained in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/6330878). (as a rule of thumb, use `===` for strings)

In order to get the server URL (commonly referred to as `hostname`), you can use the global `window` property. This has a property `window.location.hostname`, which will return for instance `stackoverflow.com`.

```js
var hostname= window.location.hostname;

if(hostname === "www.homemysiteserver.com"){
  console.log("home page");
} else if(hostname === "www.aboutmysiteserver.com"){
  console.log("about page");
} else if(hostname === "www.infomysiteserver.com"){
  console.log("about page");
}
```

Do note that the returned value may not include `www.` or `http://`,  so your use of `var server = parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();` is likely more consistent for you situation.

Comment: Yep, bad assumption on my part

Comment: I can only type so fast :P